# Returning values from a temp table if another temp table returns no rows

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to write a query that returns values from one temp table if another temp table returns no rows.

EDIT: The whole table has a following structure

```
 NAME     TYPE  DATE      VALUE
Washington  1   NULL       1000  <--default value
Washington  2   NULL        750  <--default value
Washington  3   NULL        500  <--default value
Washington  1   04.11.2015  500
Washington  2   04.11.2015  250
Washington  3   04.11.2015  100
Washington  1   07.11.2015  600
Washington  2   07.11.2015  300
Washington  3   07.11.2015  200
```

Temp table: `Name, type, date, value` where date `IS NULL` returns the 'default' values

Temp table : `Name, Type, date, value` where each unique `Name` will have 3 types (1,2,3) and each type has a different value, they all have the same date.

When there is no entry for the date column it means that the values should be 'default', which are stored in the same table under rows where date is null

I also have 8 different parameters that determine the Value but I'm only interested in '1' and '2' hence the 'case when'

So what I want to get in the end is:

```
Select * 
from temp1 
where date =GETDATE()
```

And if that doesn't exist I want it to return:

```
select * from temp2.
```

I am only interested in getting results for Today, Tomorrow and the day after tomorrow

This is what I've got so far but it's obviously not working.

I would appreciate any help I can get

```
WITH    defaultvalues
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        n.Name ,
                        Type ,
                        Value
               FROM     mytable
                        LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
                                                    AND Date IS NULL
             ),
        changedvalue
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        n.Name ,
                        type ,
                        date ,
                        CASE WHEN d.Date = GETDATE()
                                  AND Parameter = '1' THEN Value
                             WHEN Parameter = '2' THEN '0'
                        END AS CAP
               FROM     mytable
                        LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
               WHERE    Parameter IN ( '1', '2' )
             )
    SELECT  CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS ( SELECT   *
                                   FROM     changedvalue
                                   WHERE    changedvalue.Date = GETDATE() )
                 THEN ( SELECT  *
                        FROM    defaultvalues
                      )
            END
```

Comment: It is not clear from the story what you exactly want and the SQL itself is not explanatory at all. Would you please create and provide some sample data and what output you expect. You can use SqlFiddle if need be or t-SQL flex to provide data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide sample data and just basing on your SQL thinking you are only having trouble in the last part:

```
WITH  defaultvalues
        AS (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    n.Name, [type], [date], [Value] AS cap
             FROM   mytable
             LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id AND
                                         [Date] IS NULL
           ),
      changedvalue
        AS (
             SELECT DISTINCT
                    n.Name, [type], [date],
                    CASE WHEN d.Date = GETDATE() AND
                              Parameter = '1' THEN [Value]
                         WHEN Parameter = '2' THEN '0'
                    END AS CAP
             FROM   mytable
             LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
             WHERE  Parameter IN ( '1', '2' )
           )
  SELECT  *
  FROM    [changedvalue]
  UNION
  SELECT  *
  FROM    [defaultvalues]
  WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                       FROM   [changedvalue] );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to read and fully understand your question without sample data, but it seems you are looking to return values from one of two table based on a condition.

One way to achieve this, seeing that you have the same schema for both temp tables, is to simply `UNION` the results together with the conditional check in the `WHERE` clause.

I've tried to create a simplified example to show how you can do this, with the below code which is runnable if you copy and paste in to Management Studio.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (Name VARCHAR(10), [type] VARCHAR(10), [date] DATE, value int)
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (Name VARCHAR(10), [type] VARCHAR(10), [date] DATE, value int)

INSERT INTO #temp1 ( Name, type, date, value )
VALUES  ( 'bob', 'male', '2015-03-12', 123)


INSERT INTO #temp2 ( Name, type, date, value )
VALUES  ( 'jane', 'female', GETDATE(), 456)

DECLARE @switch BIT = 1
-- with @switch set to 1, #temp1 will be returned
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM #temp1
          WHERE @switch = 1
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM #temp2
          WHERE @switch = 0
        ) t1

SET @switch = 0
--with @switch set to 0, #temp2 will be returned
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM #temp1
          WHERE @switch = 1
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM #temp2
          WHERE @switch = 0
        ) t1

DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
```

I'm using the value of `@switch` on the `WHERE` condition to determine which table to call in the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
WITH    defaultvalues
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        n.Name ,
                        Type ,
                        Value
               FROM     mytable
                        LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
                                                    AND Date IS NULL
             ),
        changedvalue
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        n.Name ,
                        type ,
                        date ,
                        CASE WHEN d.Date = GETDATE()
                                  AND Parameter = '1' THEN Value
                             WHEN Parameter = '2' THEN '0'
                        END AS CAP
               FROM     mytable
                        LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
               WHERE    Parameter IN ( '1', '2' )
             ),
        final
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY c ) r
               FROM     ( SELECT    * ,
                                    1 AS c
                          FROM      changedvalue
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT    * ,
                                    2 AS c
                          FROM      defaultvalues
                        ) t
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    final
    WHERE   r = 1
```

You just union the results with different `c` column. Then rank on the column `c` and select where rank equals to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use Union to combine both answer

```
 WITH    defaultvalues
      AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    n.Name ,
                    Type ,
                    Value
           FROM     mytable
                    LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
                                                AND Date IS NULL
         ),
    changedvalue
      AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    n.Name ,
                    type ,
                    date ,
                    CASE WHEN d.Date = GETDATE()
                              AND Parameter = '1' THEN Value
                         WHEN Parameter = '2' THEN '0'
                    END AS CAP
           FROM     mytable
                    LEFT JOIN nametable AS n ON mytable.x = r.Id
           WHERE    Parameter IN ( '1', '2' )
         )
        (  SELECT   *
           FROM     changedvalue                                   
           WHERE    changedvalue.Date = GETDATE() )
          UNION
        ( SELECT    *
          FROM    defaultvalues 
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM changedvalue ))
        END
```